# Avoid copying element multiple times in sub-lists

Tags: python, list, copy

I am creating a list with several sub-lists and sub-sub-lists like so:

```
a = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2]
b = [[]] * 3
c = [[]] * 4
# Final list.
d = [[b, c]] * len(a)
```

I need to create it this way because it depends on the length of various other lists, this is just a simplified example.

When I try to append a single element to `d`:

```
d[0][0][0].append(a[2])
```

I get the same element repeated throughout the list:

```
[[[[0.4], [0.4], [0.4]], [[], [], [], []]], [[[0.4], [0.4], [0.4]], [[], [], [], []]], [[[0.4], [0.4], [0.4]], [[], [], [], []]], [[[0.4], [0.4], [0.4]], [[], [], [], []]], [[[0.4], [0.4], [0.4]], [[], [], [], []]]]
```

I understand this is a problem with how I'm creating `d` but I'm not sure how can I prevent this behaviour.

Comment: change your list to `d = [[[[], [], []], [[], [], [], []]]] * 3` and change the `* 3` to different lengths when you append a[2] and it will be clear.

Comment: might be because of pointer issues. you can try replacing [[b, c]] with [[list(b), list(c)]].